# The terminology of fixing one input of a multivariate function

Tags: functions, terminology

Say $f(x,y)$ is a multivariate function.
Is there a terminology for the function $x\mapsto f(x,y^*)$, where $y^*$ is some fixed value?

To be more specific, what is the **name** and the right **notation** of this function?

Comment: I think $f_{y^*}(x)$ could be the case. For every fixed value of $y$ you have a function that depend only from $x$

Comment: @TurquoiseTilt That is not necessarily a bad notation, but it could be confused for a partial derivative.  Another possible notation is $f(\cdot,y^*)$.

Comment: @XanderHenderson Thanks for suggesting.  Do you also know the name of this function?

Comment: In my calc 3 class I believe it was called  'trace'

Comment: @Max0815 I really don't like the idea of calling this the "trace", as that term already has meaning in the context of, for example, linear operators.  Google also convinces me that calling this partial evaluation the "trace" is likely to be quite confusing.

Answer (score 0):

The function you're referring to, where $y$ is fixed at a specific value $y^*$, is called the partial evaluation or partial specialization of $f$ with respect to $y$. The notation commonly used for this function is $f(\cdot, y^*)$ or $f_{y^*}(\cdot)$.